# codeigniter fatal error Call to a member function cookie() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have Codeigniter v202, and php version 5.2.17
my site works just good in my local but in the server i keep getting this error message in everypage, message in error log is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function cookie() on a non-object in /path/to/libraries/Session.php on line 138

and in page i have

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: MY_CONTROLLER_NAME::$input
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 138

this is line 138:

```
$session = $this->CI->input->cookie($this->sess_cookie_name);
```

library is the original, i didnt make any changes on it. 
please help!

Comment: Please provide relevant code to your problem so that we can help you with it.

Comment: Why $this->CI? where are you working? a regular controller? did you call the parent __construct()?

Comment: it is CI's own session library, and same error in all controllers

Comment: I think you're getting something wrong, reading the "undefined property" error you posted. Could you please write more of the code you're using, and *where*? Are you extending the library or just calling it in the controller?

Comment: @DamienPirsy i got the error in any controller and the function even to echo 'phpinfo()' with CI controller i got the error message. i thought there was something wrong with my autoload models but i remove them still the same issue.

Comment: @muminaydin Does your controller extends CI_COntroller or a custom one?

Comment: @DamienPirsy it extends CI_Controller, but not any custom one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was wrong.
i had

> setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR');

in my **/index.php**. 
so weird but *session* library did not initialize *core input*. it took me long to find but when i echo

```
echo var_dump($this->CI);
```

there was ? (question mark) instead of the char *I* then it was *?nput*. my locale didn't capitalize char **i** as **I**, that was the problem. weird thing is it worked in localhost but didn't work on the server.

Comment: I have same problem too. If you want to set locale to TR you must set locale in your controller's constructor.
public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8');
 }